# Not able to login from an html form through php

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a login form on a bootstrap theme. Code for the login html page is

```
<form role="form" action="login.php" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email" name="email">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password" name="password">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login" />                 
</form>
```

Login.php page is:

```
<?
$host="host"; // Host name 
$username="username"; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name="db_name"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="tbl_name"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// username and password sent from form 
$myemail=$_POST['myemail']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword']; 

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myemail = stripslashes($myemail);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myemail = mysql_real_escape_string($myemail);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE email='$myemail' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1){

// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
session_register("myemail");
session_register("mypassword"); 
header("location:index.html");
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
?>
```

The problem is that even if i put the correct login details it is still giving the message:- "Wrong Username or Password" 
Would appreciate if anyone could point out the errors

Comment: Do not use `session_register`, it is deprecated and removed in php >= 5.4, use `session_start` and `$_SESSION` superglobal.

Comment: Same goes for MySQL, use MySQLi or PDO

Comment: +1: Don't use mysql_* functions, they're deprecated too! Try mysqli_* or PDO instead.

Comment: Your input field name is just `email` and `password`. But in login.php you takes `$_POST['myemail']` and `$_POST['mypassword']`

Comment: One more thing: Hash your password before save! At least use md5, but sha1 or bcrypt would be better.

Comment: @Gerifield [**MD5 is old**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) (*circa 1992*) and is considered broken. `bcrypt`, or [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471) or PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function. For PHP < 5.5 use the [`password_hash() compatibility pack`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) are much better ;)

Comment: @Fred-ii- I know, thats why I said at least. It's still better than nothing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your form elements are called `name="email"` and `name="password"`

but your POSTs are:

```
$myemail=$_POST['myemail']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword'];
```

change them to:

```
$myemail=$_POST['email']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['password'];
```

---

***Sidenote/password related:***

If you are saving passwords in plain text which is not recommended, I suggest you use [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471) or PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function.
For PHP < 5.5 use the [`password_hash() compatibility pack`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

***Believe me,*** if you intend on going LIVE with this, it's just a matter of time before your site gets hacked. I've seen quite a few questions posted in the past 6 months in relation to that, ***be safe, not sorry.***

Plus,  use [**`mysqli_` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *it's much safer.*

---

**Footnotes:**

I noticed you are using `session_register()`

This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0.

as per the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-register.php

---

Plus, add `exit();` after `header("location:index.html");`

Answer (score 0):

Your input field name is just `email` and `password`.

But in login.php you takes `$_POST['myemail']` and `$_POST['mypassword']`

Change this part and please have a try

```
// username and password sent from form 
$myemail=$_POST['email']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['password'];
```

Answer (score 0):

change this in your code

for this::

```
$myemail=$_POST['myemail']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword'];
```

to::

```
$myemail=$_POST['email']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['password'];
```

Comment: The very same has been said twice already and much earlier too, like almost an hour earlier.